# Get the last day of a month on powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to put in a `.txt` file the first day and the last day of the months using PowerShell.

In the exemple below i was trying to get the first and the last day of July, but i'm just getting the first day. The second line of the script isn't working.

```
@PowerShell "(Get-Date).AddMonths(1).ToString('01/MM/yyyy')" >>dates.txt 
$LastDayInMonthString = "$($(get-date).AddMonths(1).ToString("dd/mm/yyy"))$LastDayInMonth" >>dates.txt
```

Someone can say me what is wrong?

I wanted a .txt file like it: `01/07/2018, 31/07/2018`.
The first line write the first day of next month,
and second line write the last day of that month.

Comment: The powershell part wrapped in ".." ends with the first line. What output do you expect/want.

Comment: I wanted a .txt file like it: 01/07/2018 31/07/2018. The first line write the first day of next month, and second line write the last day of that month. But i dont'k know what i did wrong.

Comment: Add 2 months, select the first day of that month (similar of watch you already did: `01/MM/yyyy`), subtract one day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit removed the for only date unneccessary time adjustments**

In PowerShell to get the first day and last of ***next*** month

```
$CIGB = New-Object System.Globalization.CultureInfo('en-GB')
'{0}, {1}' -f (Get-Date -Day 1).AddMonths(1).ToString('d',$CIGB),
  (Get-Date -Day 1).AddMonths(2).AddDays(-1).ToString('d',$CIGB)|sc dates.txt
```

The $CIGB is neccessary for me because my local date separator overrides the `/`
If your short date format `'d'`  returns `dd/MM/yyyy` the first line and the `,$CIGB` can be removed.

```
01/07/2018, 31/07/2018
```

This can be wrapped in a single (albeit quite long) line.

```
powershell -nop -c "$CIGB=New-Object System.Globalization.CultureInfo('en-GB');'{0}, {1}' -f (Get-Date -Day 1).AddMonths(1).ToString('d',$CIGB),(Get-Date -Day 1).AddMonths(2).AddDays(-1).ToString('d',$CIGB)">>dates.txt
```

---

```
> type dates.txt
01/07/2018, 31/07/2018
```

Comment: Good! And if i want put a ' , ' after the date? like: 01/07/2018,
31/07/2018,

Comment: Change the string format operator to `'{0}, {1}' -f` (the dates are inserted in place of `{0}` and `{1}`)

Comment: Worked fine! Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 20):

Much simpler solution is to call into the DaysInMonth function

```
[DateTime]::DaysInMonth(2018, 11)
```

For the current month that would look like:

```
$today = get-date
$lastDay = [DateTime]::DaysInMonth($today.Year, $today.Month)
$firstDate = [DateTime]::new($today.Year, $today.Month, 1)
$lastDate  = [DateTime]::new($today.Year, $today.Month, $lastDay)

$firstDate
$lastDate
```

This also works around any hindering daylight savings changes and other weird things that can happen with timezones etc.

Or if pure strings are all you need:

```
(get-date -Format "yyyy/MM") + "/1"
(get-date -Format "yyyy/MM") + "/" + [DateTime]::DaysInMonth((get-date).Year, (get-date).Month)
```

Comment: But that returns the current month data not the next ones.

Comment: The function uses get-date as input. Feed it whichever year/month number you want.

Comment: I don't think it **is** or looks **much** simpler when you get the next month and put it into the desired format `01/07/2018, 31/07/2018`

Comment: Nice, clean solution @jessehouwing! I like it and have used it in my script to keep files from the last day of each month.

Answer (score 4):

An easy way is to take the last day of the previous year and add 1..12 months to it:

```
1..12 | % { (New-Object DateTime(2017,12,31)).AddMonths($_) }
```

Output will be in the user's date/time format, in my case Dutch:

```
woensdag 31 januari 2018 00:00:00
woensdag 28 februari 2018 00:00:00
zaterdag 31 maart 2018 00:00:00
maandag 30 april 2018 00:00:00
donderdag 31 mei 2018 00:00:00
zaterdag 30 juni 2018 00:00:00
dinsdag 31 juli 2018 00:00:00
vrijdag 31 augustus 2018 00:00:00
zondag 30 september 2018 00:00:00
woensdag 31 oktober 2018 00:00:00
vrijdag 30 november 2018 00:00:00
maandag 31 december 2018 00:00:00
```

If required you can format it as you need it, e.g.

```
1..12 | % { (New-Object DateTime(2017,12,31)).AddMonths($_).ToString("yyyyMMdd") }

20180131
20180228
20180331
20180430
20180531
20180630
20180731
20180831
20180930
20181031
20181130
20181231
```

Answer (score 4):

This seems simple enough

```
$firstDate = [DateTime]::new($reportDate.Year, $reportDate.Month, 1)
$lastDate=$firstDate.AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Strings can be passed to Get-Date. The -Format parameter also accepts strings/variables.

```
# Get the previous month
$LastMonth = (Get-Date).AddMonths(-1)

# Format the first day of the month
$FirstDayOfMonth = $LastMonth | Get-Date -Format "yyyy/MM/01"

# Calculate the number of days (last day) in the month
$LastDay = [DateTime]::DaysInMonth($LastMonth.Year, $LastMonth.Month)

# Use it in the format parameter
$LastDayOfMonth = $LastMonth | Get-Date -Format "yyyy/MM/$lastDay"
```