# To create XML output file from PowerShell script

Tags: xml, powershell, powershell-2.0

To create below XML output from PowerShell script:

```xml
<Trigger>
  <Value1>20181231</value1> 
  <value2>20180531</>
  <value3>20180531</value3>
  <value4>FINANCE</value4>
  <value5 />
  <value6 />
</Trigger>
```

Value1 is this years end date. Value2 & value 3 is this months end date. How to create above XML from PowerShell script?

Comment: What have you tried? Have any work to show? What part exactly are you stuck at? Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. If you need help learning how to code or troubleshoot something then this is the place for you. If you need code from scratch then you should hire a developer.

Comment: [Calculate the dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50785896/get-the-last-day-of-a-month-on-powershell) and insert them into a [double quoted here string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules?view=powershell-6) which you write to file.

Comment: It would help if the xml was valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
## Q:\Test\2019\05\21\SO_56237520.ps1

$ThisYearEndDate = (Get-Date -Month 1 -Day 1).AddYears(1).AddDays(-1).ToString('yyyyMMdd')
$ThisMonthEndDate= (Get-Date -Day 1).AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1).ToString('yyyyMMdd')
$File = '.\Sample.xml'

@"
<Trigger>
  <Value1>$ThisYearEndDate</Value1>
  <value2>$ThisMonthEndDate</value2>
  <value3>$ThisMonthEndDate</value3>
  <value4>FINANCE</value4>
  <value5 />
  <value6 />
</Trigger>
"@ | Set-Content $File -Encoding UTF8

$XML = [XML](Get-Content $File)

$XML.Trigger
```

Sample output

```
> .\SO_56237520.ps1


Value1 : 20191231
value2 : 20190531
value3 : 20190531
value4 : FINANCE
value5 :
value6 :
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution using XElement:

```
using namespace system.xml.linq
$CurrentDate = Get-Date
$YearEnd = Get-Date -Year $CurrentDate.Year -Month 12 -Day 31 -Format yyyyMMdd
$MonthEnd = Get-Date -Year $CurrentDate.Year -Month $CurrentDate.Month -Day ([datetime]::DaysInMonth($CurrentDate.Year,$CurrentDate.Month)) -Format yyyyMMdd

$x = [xelement]::new("Trigger",
    [xelement]::new("Value1",$YearEnd),
    [xelement]::new("Value2",$MonthEnd),
    [xelement]::new("Value3",$MonthEnd),
    [xelement]::new("Value4","FINANCE"),
    [xelement]::new("Value5",""),
    [xelement]::new("Value6",""))

$x.tostring() | Set-Content -Path "x.xml"
```

This outputs the XML structure to the file x.xml in the current directory.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is how to load and save an xml:

```
[xml]$xml = get-content file.xml
$xml.save('file.xml')
```

And there is a convertto-xml command:

```
$xml = [pscustomobject]@{Value1='20181231'} | ConvertTo-Xml -NoTypeInformation
$xml.save('file.xml')
get-content file.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Objects>
  <Object>
    <Property Name="Value1">20181231</Property>
  </Object>
</Objects>
```

But it's not quite that simple.